# when creating Hive table against csv saved in S3, do I absolutely have to order fields in the order of comma separated values for rows in csv?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

when creating Hive table against csv saved in S3, do I absolutely have to order fields in the order of comma separated values for rows in csv? the csv has the first row as header. I understand that csv is row based not columnar, but was wondering if there is a way to match the value of the header with the field name of the hive table and order columns differently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, columns in the table definition (DDL) should be in the same order as in the underlying csv files. You can skip header from being selected using `tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")`.

See also [Create Table manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable).